# Node.js Iterator interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, iterator

I am reading the MDN guide on [Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) and I implemented the following example :

```
function Range(low, high){
  this.low = low;
  this.high = high;
}
Range.prototype.__iterator__ = function(){
  return new RangeIterator(this);
};

function RangeIterator(range){
  this.range = range;
  this.current = this.range.low;
}
RangeIterator.prototype.next = function(){
  if (this.current > this.range.high)
    throw StopIteration;
  else
    return this.current++;
};

var range = new Range(3, 5);
for (var i in range) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

But I get this :

```
low
high
__iterator__
```

Where it should have returned :

```
3
4
5
```

Is it possible to implement this as expected in Node.js?

**Note:** I am using `node --harmony myscript.js`.

### ** Edit **

I should also note that I am aware that `__iterator__` is a [Mozilla-feature only](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/08/23/iterators-in-js-17-cool-stuff-you-cant-use-yet/). I'd like to know what's the equivalent in Node.js. Or what's the next best thing.

Also, I'd like to *not* use a generator for this as I want the iteration to be free of any conditional tests.

My conclusion is that the only equivalent is

```
Range.prototype.each = function (cb) {
  for (var i = this.low; i <= this.high; i++) {
     cb(i);
  }
};

//...
range.each(function (i) {
  console.log(i);
});
```

Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code had a bug where you wrote `for (var i in range)` instead of `for (var i of range)`. The `in` keyword prints out the object's properties, you want to use `of` to actually get the iterator values.

Anyway, Node.js now has better harmony support since the question was asked. Here's an updated code sample which works out of the box on Node 4.2. The __iterator__ name was changed to Symbol.iterator, and the StopIteration exception isn't used.

```
"use strict";

function Range(low, high){
  this.low = low;
  this.high = high;
}
Range.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function(){
  return new RangeIterator(this);
};

function RangeIterator(range){
  this.range = range;
  this.current = this.range.low;
}
RangeIterator.prototype.next = function(){
  let result = {done: this.current > this.range.high, value: this.current};
  this.current++;
  return result;
};

var range = new Range(3, 5);
for (var i of range) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Actually, I just tested your code in Node 4.0 and it does work out of the box *without* the `--harmony` flag. :) When you edit your answer to fix these details, I'll choose it as the solution to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is.**

Generators and iterators are part of ECMAScript 6 / JavaScript 1.7. Node has support for them but you need to activate them, when starting you script.

For example:

```
node --harmony_generators --harmony_iteration your_script.js
```

Take a look at this [blog post](http://h3manth.com/new/blog/2013/es6-on-nodejs/) for more information.

Comment: If you look at the flags, I have specified that I'm using the `--harmony` features... I added the notice in the question.

Comment: @YanickRochon When I typed my answer the edit was there. But does matter, apperantly this does not help.

Comment: @YanickRochon It seem like generator where added in the latest, but unstable node.js version. Are you sure use the 0.11.x branch of node.js?

Comment: with all due respect, this question has nothing to do with generators. I am already using generators and everything works fine. The problem does not lie there; Mozilla implements the `Object.prototype.__iterator__`, which Node.js does not yet support, and I want to know if the equivalent is possible in Node.js; meaning  implementing the object's prototype in a way where `for (var key in obj)` does not return the object's property, but the iterator's values.